# Fibonacci Sequence Error in C#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, sequence, fibonacci

I've recently started learning C# (having learnt other languages) and I'm trying to create a function that generates the fibonacci sequence to the 'nth' term using a while loop and then returns the value of the 'nth' term. 
My current code is this:

```
    void fibonacci(int n)
    {
        int[] terms = { 0, 1 };
        int i = 2;

        while (i<=n)
        {
            terms.Concat( terms[i-1] + terms[i-2] );
            i += 1;
        }

        return terms[n];
    }
```

My understanding of C# is very poor as visual studio is telling me that I can't use 'Concat' with int[] - I'm trying to append the array with the new values. Any help would be great.

Comment: your function type should be int[] :    int[]  fibonacci(int n)

Comment: @T-D - The OP wants to return the value at the passed in _index_. The return type should be `int`, not `int[]`.

Comment: @Oded yes you are right , it should be `int`, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is the best approach you can use in C# for Fibonacci calculation: http://ilyatereschuk.blogspot.com/2013/12/blog-post.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in C# are fixed length.

If you want to use a variable length collection, use a strongly typed `List<T>` instead, which has an `Add` method:

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    var terms = new List<int>{ 0, 1 };
    int i = 2;

    while (i<=n)
    {
        terms.Add( terms[i-1] + terms[i-2] );
        i += 1;
    }

    return terms[n];
}
```

Comment: How would I then convert the returned value to a string?

Comment: @galacticfan - **every** object in .NET has a `ToString()` method... Some of the built in functions used to display string will call that automatically (`System.Console.Write`, for example, or `String.Format`).

Comment: I forgot to add the () brackets as it's a method, not a property. *Face plants into desk*.

Comment: @galacticfan - [I know the feeling](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/226603842.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can't append to an array. In .Net, arrays have constant size and you can't resize them after creation.

Instead, you should use [`List<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and its [`Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use list and change your code to:

```
    int fibonacci(int n)
    {
        List<int> terms = new List<int> { 0, 1 };
        int i = 2;

        while (i<=n)
        {
            terms.Add(terms[i-1] + terms[i-2]);
            i += 1;
        }

        return terms[n];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add items to an array as it has fixed length. Use `List<int>` instead of array

Answer (score 0):

Don't append values to an array.  arrays have static size and you can't resize them after creation.
 use

```
 List<int> and its Add() method instead of array.
```

here is your solution for fibonacci series.

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    var terms = new List<int>{ 0, 1 };
    int i = 2;

    while (i<=n)
    {
        terms.Add( terms[i-1] + terms[i-2] );
        i += 1;
    }

    return terms[n];
}
```

also can be done like this :

```
class FibonacciSeries
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a num till which you want fibonacci series : ");
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int num1, num2;
        num1 = num2 = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(num1);
        if (val > num2)
        {
            while (num2 < val)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num2);
                num2 += num1;
                num1 = num2 - num1;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

in your array format here is the solution

```
public int[] FibonacciSeriesArray(int num)
{
     int[] arr = new int[num+1];
     arr[0] = 0;
     arr[1] = 1;

     for (int startnum = 2; startnum  <= num; startnum++)
     {
        arr[startnum] = arr[startnum - 1] + arr[startnum - 2];
     }
     return arr;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned fixing the array size.

Well, maybe I'm missing something, but you could do:

```
int[] FibonacciArray(int n)
{
    int[] F = new int[n+1];
    F[0] = 0;
    F[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        F[i] = F[i - 1] + F[i - 2];
    }

    return F;
}
```

It's in average **2.5x faster** than the version using a list.

But as often there is no free-lunch: the drawback is that your **memory consumption is not smoothed**: you pay upfront for all the memory you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much more efficient way of finding fibonnaci numbers.

[image]

```
    public static IEnumerable<double> FibList(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            yield return Math.Round(Fib(i));
        }
    }

    public static double Fib(double n)
    {
        double golden = 1.61803398875;

        return (n == 0 || n == 1) ? 1 : (Math.Pow(golden, n) - Math.Pow(-golden, -n))/Math.Sqrt(5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as a recursion, and not as a loop.

```
private static int fibonacci(int fib)
    {
        if (fib == 2 || fib == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return fibonacci(fib - 1) + fibonacci(fib - 2);
        }
    }
```